# What %inline really do on Idris? and when to use it?

Tags: idris

Reading Idris2 code I've seen several cases of functions "decorated" with `%inline` and also `%tcinline` I've been searching for a clear explanation about it but haven't found anything except that it "can" be used for giving some "hints" to help on foreign calls, but it's not clear what's the main purpose of it and when it should be used or when should not be used.

Additionally it would be really good to know if these "decorators" which happen to start with `%` have any common purpose.

Answer (score 2):

From the [change log](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris2/blob/268a3520f3f3395cb1f5785aa2716a23c68c9c23/CHANGELOG.md#v020):

> New function flag `%tcinline` which means that the function should be inlined for the purposes of totality checking (but otherwise not inlined). This can be used as a hint for totality checking, to make the checker look inside functions that it otherwise might not.

From the [documentation on pragmas](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris2/blob/094a9ab06d68bea216d892058c5e323738cab858/docs/source/reference/pragmas.rst#inline):

> `%inline` Instruct the compiler to inline the following definition when it is applied. It is generally best to let the compiler and the backend you are using optimize code based on its predetermined rules, but if you want to
> force a function to be inlined when it is called, this pragma will force it.